# Custom file sorting in VS2010 Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, solution-explorer

Is there any way to force Solution Explorer in Visual Studio 2010 to sort files alphabetically **but** in order *.h, *.inl and *.cpp?

I want to have

```
Dummy.h
Dummy.inl
Dummy.cpp
Emmy.h
Emmy.cpp
Grammy.h
Grammy.cpp
```

instead of

```
Dummy.cpp
Dummy.h
Dummy.inl
Emmy.cpp
Emmy.h
Grammy.cpp
Grammy.h
```

Comment: Then that wouldn't be alphabetically!

Comment: @CodyGray I know that :) that is why the **but**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no such feature built in.

I don't know of any extension or add-in that supports this, either, but I imagine that you could create one. Get started with the [Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441.aspx), or browse the [Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search) for something that serves a similar purpose.

However, the Solution Explorer *does* support grouping related files (such as headers, resources, and code files) into virtual folders. Turn that feature on by deselecting the second button to the left at the top of the Solution Explorer window labeled "Show All Files".